# Mobile application testing

Tags: testing, mobile, internationalization

Let's say I have a mobile application that is to be offered on many different mobile platforms like Blackberry, iOS, Android etc.

Is there any easy way to test across all platforms in many languages, something like a virtualization platform like VMWare Workstation on Windows?

Do any of these platforms have standalone emulators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlackBerry, iOS and Android all have standalone emulators.  Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7 do as well (the WP7 emulator is Best-In-Class without a doubt).

There is no easy way (or any way at all, really) to *write* an application that will run on all of these platforms, let alone to test such an application.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I worded my question poorly, the application already exists (obviously different versions per platform). Thanks for the response!

Comment: The testing for each version of the app would be dependent on the platform of each version, so there's no way to test different device versions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

check  http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/ ,IBM Worklight provides an open, comprehensive and advanced mobile application platform for smartphones and tablets, helping organizations of all sizes .

Can develop same app for Iphone,Android, blackberry,just needs to chand the environment for three wich is provided with the worklight tool.